# Is there a way to have the standard controller dynamic in Vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page which i am using in a managed package and i currently have it assigned to opportunity. This page is embeded into the pagelayout. Now i am thinking of having the ability to use this VF page for custom objects. but obviously i cant embed it if i dont have standard controller  assigned to custom object and i would not have access to name of the custom object in customer org.

Are there any creative ideas to have the VF page be usable in managed package for custom objects?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. But you can implement a component and put all the login in to it. Then use it on all other pages.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood it. Can i embed the component into a pagelayout?

Comment: No, I mean to insert a component to the visualforce page. Then you could use only one component for multiple object types. But you have to have multiple "container" visualforce pages for each object page layout. I don't think we can use a variable for the `standardController="{!someVar}"`